# Turn Off the lights algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I am creating the turnOff algorithm in Python. I want to include the matrix of numbers.   It states imagine a row of n lights, numbered 1 to n that can be turned on or off under certain conditions. The first light can be turned on or off anytime. Each of the other lights can be turned on or off only when the preceding light is on and all other lights before it are off.  If all the lights are on initially, how can you turn them all off? For three lights numbered 1 to 3, you can take the following steps, where i indicates a light is on and 0 indicates the light is off.

- 111 3 lights on
- 011 turon off light 1
- 010 turn off light 3
- 110 turn on light 1
- 100 turn off light 2
- 000 turn off light 1

How would I include the matrix of numbers in my program?

Here is my code so far:

```
def turnOff(n):
    #if number of lights is less than one
    if (n < 1):
        return
    #if number of lights is greater or equal to one
    if (n == 1):
        print("Turn off light", n)
    else:
        if(n > 2):
            turnOff(n - 2)
            print("Turn off light", n)
        if(n > 2):
            turnOn(n - 2)
            turnOff(n - 1)


def turnOn(n):
    # if number of lights is less than one
    if(n < 1):
        return
    # if number of lights is 1
    if(n == 1):
        print("Turn on light", n)
    else:
        turnOn(n - 1)
        if(n > 2):
           turnOff(n - 2)
           print("Turn on light", n)
        if(n > 2):
            # call method
            turnOn(n - 2)


def main():
    n = int(input("Please enter a number of lights: "))
    print()
    print(turnOn(n))
    # print("Number of steps", count)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Please enter a number of lights: 3

- Turn on light 1
- Turn off light 1
- Turn on light 3
- Turn on light 1

Heres what I am getting as an output.  I would like to add a matrix.

Comment: All I want to do is create a game.  Thats all I want to do.

Comment: If all lights are initially on, why does your main code call `turnOn(n)`? Also, why are you happy with the fact that the first output is "Turn on light 1", when it is already on? You're asking for adding a matrix in the output, but is your code really correct?

Comment: I think we have a bit of a problem understanding your problem statement. You say you can only turn a light on if all previous lights are on? Does the same logic work for turning a light off? Why do you need a matrix? you could just use a binary vector. Also do you know what bit shifting is?

Comment: Code apart, I can't understand what do you mean with "How would I include the matrix of numbers in my program" / "I would like to add a matrix". Do you mean you whant to **print** the results as a "matrix" (so your first example of three lights on would print like: first row:111, second: 011, third: 010...and so on with the last: 000) or you whant to **create** a matrix with all the permutations stored inside, one for each row (basically a matrix containing the rows i writed before)...or you mean something else?

Comment: @Ido_f also your question *"Does the same logic work for turning a light off?"* has an answer in the same rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a list variable that will hold the state of your lights.  As you turn lights on or off, you will update the corresponding entries in the list.  You can use this list to display the current state and to validate which lights can be toggled.

```
numberOfLights = int(input("Please enter a number of lights: "))
lights         = [1] * numberOfLights
while 1 in lights:    
    lightIndex = int(input(f"{lights} toggle which light ? ")) - 1
    if lightIndex > 0 and lights.index(1) != lightIndex-1:
        print("You cannot toggle that light")
        continue
    lights[lightIndex] = 1 - lights[lightIndex]
print(f"{lights} success !!")
```

*Note that list indexes start at zero (not 1). That's the reason for subtracting 1 from the light number entered by the user*

Sample game:

```
Please enter a number of lights: 4
[1, 1, 1, 1] toggle which light ? 1
[0, 1, 1, 1] toggle which light ? 2
You cannot toggle that light
[0, 1, 1, 1] toggle which light ? 1
[1, 1, 1, 1] toggle which light ? 2
[1, 0, 1, 1] toggle which light ? 1
[0, 0, 1, 1] toggle which light ? 4
[0, 0, 1, 0] toggle which light ? 2
You cannot toggle that light
[0, 0, 1, 0] toggle which light ? 1
[1, 0, 1, 0] toggle which light ? 2
[1, 1, 1, 0] toggle which light ? 1
[0, 1, 1, 0] toggle which light ? 3
[0, 1, 0, 0] toggle which light ? 1
[1, 1, 0, 0] toggle which light ? 2
[1, 0, 0, 0] toggle which light ? 1
[0, 0, 0, 0] success !!
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a number written in binary.  Watch how the bits change as we decrement it, and watch how the *differences* between adjacent bits change.

```
  x     bits of x     bits of x XORed with adjacent higher bit
 ==   ===========  ===========================================
 15       1111        1000
 14       1110        1001
 13       1101        1011
 12       1100        1010
 11       1011        1110
 10       1010        1111  <--these bits are lights.  Here they are all on
  9       1001        1101
  8       1000        1100
      ... bla bla bla ...
  1       0001        0001
  0       0000        0000
```

Notice that, starting at the right-most bit, that last column of bits follows your rules!

At any point you have two choices -- you can flip the first light, or you can find the first 1 and flip the next light.  Both choices correspond to either an increment or decrement of x.

Let *G(x)* be the number you get by XORing each bit of *x* with the next-highest one.  (G, because it's a Gray code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code)

Now it becomes very easy to answer all the questions about how to get from one sequence of lights to another.  If you want to start with all the lights on and turn them off, just:

- Start with *x=10*, so that *G(x)=15* (1111 in binary)
- Decrement it to 0.  That will, of course, take 10 steps.
- Write out G(x) at any time if you want to know what the lights are